# telnet script error in vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I am writing a script in vba to perform telnet and following is part of the code.

```
Dim vPath As String
Dim vFile As String
Dim vFTPServ As String
Dim ServSlot As String
Dim fNum As Long



 vPath = Application.InputBox("Enter the File Directory")
 vFile = Application.InputBox("Enter the File Name")
 vFTPServ = Application.InputBox("Enter the IP Address")
 ServSlot = Application.InputBox("Enter the slot #")



 Dim WshShell As Object
 Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 WshShell.Run "cmd.exe"
 WScript.Sleep 1000
```

it seems as the code works fine till the cmd.exe and then displays the runtime error "424" - object required. for the Wscript.sleep 1000 line.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Wscript is not a object you declared. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to telnet to the desired ip and port and send some commands. How would you declare it then?

Answer (score 0):

The generic way to declare an object like WScript is

```
Dim WshShell As Object

set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```